# Python Regular expression to isolate @ character from Text and replace by {{ and }}

Tags: python, regex

How would I go about using regx to find all @ character in like this pattern @sonetext@ and get replace by {{ for start pattern and }} for end of pattern Here is an example:

@java.nio.charsets.StandardCharsets.UTF_8@ -- > {{java.nio.charsets.StandardCharsets.UTF_8}}

```
"@java.nio.charsets.StandardCharsets.UTF_8@ is the only.&#xD;&#xA;&#xD;&#xA;To resolve this Destroy @MetaDexCharset@ - Destroy @JavaProperties.Io.ENCODING@* -&amp;gt;"
```

needs to look like

```
{{java.nio.charsets.StandardCharsets.UTF_8}} is the only.&#xD;&#xA;&#xD;&#xA;To resolve this Destroy {{MetaDexCharset}} - Destroy {{JavaProperties.Io.ENCODING}}* -&amp;gt;
```

Comment: Can you improve the formatting of your question ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Is this what you want:

```
import re
text = '"@java.nio.charsets.StandardCharsets.UTF_8@ is the only.&#xD;&#xA;&#xD;&#xA;To resolve this Destroy @MetaDexCharset@ - Destroy @JavaProperties.Io.ENCODING@* -&amp;gt;"'
text = re.sub(r'@(.*?)@', lambda x: '{{' + x.group(1) + '}}', text)
print(text)
```